# How to draw a string to the screen character by character

Tags: string, loops, animation, text, processing

I have the below code that creates a delay in-between drawing characters from a string, this works using println() however does not work when using the text() function. The code is supposed to wait an allotted time then print the next character, I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```js
int startTimer;
int waitTime = 500;
boolean funcRun = true;

void setup(){
 size(500, 500);
 startTimer = millis();
}

void draw(){
  while(funcRun){
    textAnim("hello");
  }
}

void textAnim(String textInput){
int counter = 0;
int x = 10;

while(counter < textInput.length()){
    if(millis() - startTimer>waitTime){
      text(textInput.charAt(counter), x , 100);
       startTimer = millis();
       ++counter;
       x = x + 10;
    }
    funcRun = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The displayed screen is updated at the end of the `draw()` function. So your while loop is fully executed and the completed text is shown. You'll have to modify the code such that it will constantly refresh/redraw the screen, and updates the displayed text based on the time loop.

For example like this:

```
int currentTime;
int waitTime = 500;
int characters_to_display = 0;
boolean stringComplete = false;

String textInput = "Hello"; 

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  currentTime = millis();
}

void draw() {
  // Update text to be shown. increaseCharIndex() is called while the text is not yet fully displayed
  if (stringComplete == false) {
    increaseCharIndex();
  }

  //Draw screen:

  // draw background to clear screen
  background(0);
  // display (a substring of) the text
  text(textInput.substring(0, characters_to_display), 10, 100);
}

void increaseCharIndex() {
  // if the waitperiod has passed, increase the number of characters to be displayed
  if (millis() - currentTime>waitTime) {
    currentTime = millis();
    characters_to_display++;
  }    
  // if the full text will be shown, end the call to increaseCharIndex()
  if (characters_to_display >= textInput.length())
  {
    stringComplete = true;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot of sense.